# What are some way to decide if a e-commerce site is reliable?

Tags: united-states, financial-literacy, scams

I am planning to travel to US for holidays, and my friend in US told me that gift card from mygiftcardsite. Here's [the website](http://wwwmygiftcardsitecom.org/), and here's [where](https://www2.consumercardaccess.com/main/mygiftcardusb/Home) you can register/view your transaction details.

Truth to be told, I am not at all impressed with the website design. It does look quite scammy to me.

Anyone uses this before? My questions for those who know:

1. I can't seem to be able to buy them from online, may I know where I can buy them?
2. Is this a valid debit card issued by US banks?
3. Can I use this to buy digital goods at online store ( such as iTunes or Amazon) that requires a valid US credit/debit card and a valid US billing address?
4. Is this the card that is being mentioned [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26361/1665)?
5. **Most importantly, is it safe to use**?

Comment: http://www.seomastering.com/audit/wwwmygiftcardsitecom.org/ Alexa Ranking of 2 Million, Estimated worth of $84, Google Page Rank of 0/10. I won't be buying from this website.

Comment: While it isn't on topic to answer about the one specific site in question, I think you can get a good answer that has a how-to feel for it if we make it generic enough.

Answer (score 9):

I can only answer your last question.

**NO** that site, in my opinion, is not safe to use.

Why? First look at the actual URL (spaces to break the auto-link)

http: // wwwmygiftcardsitecom.org/

Only a scammer buys a domain of '**www**---**com.org**' notice there's no dots in there. They want you to think you're going to www.mygiftcardsite.com ... but you're not.

A casual Google for the URL reveals that there are a lot of different versions of that URL listed, which is either people pulling the same scam or one person trying to avoid blacklists and come up in as many searches as possible.

Lastly all these sites tend to link to each other with positive reviews which is generally a red flag.

Now, I can't find a definitive link with reports of someone being scammed by them, but then they're doing a good job of filling up the search results as well and that's also the reason there are so many different variations of the URL.

I would not even consider risking it, in fact I'd probably check you have a decent virus checker running if you did go to that site (mine didn't flag anything, but then I also have scripts and ads blocked ...).

I'd find a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Anyone uses this before? 
A:  The website wwwmygiftcardsitecom.org appears to be a marketing website and contains a ton of affiliate links.

Q: Most importantly, is it safe to use?
A: The link is as safe as the affiliate websites you are redirected to.  The website mentioned mygiftcardsite.com is for people who already own giftcards and wish to check the balance.

(I am not affiliated with any of the websites below)

Places where you can purchase giftcards:
http://www.cardhub.com/us/gift-cards/
Check out the 'Anywhere' category for gift visa cards.

Other options, you can purchase iTunes and Amazon giftcards here:
http://www.cardpool.com/buy-gift-cards
https://www.raise.com/

As someone who has worked in international tourist destinations, your local bank's Visa or Mastercard will work in almost all situations while you are traveling.  They convert currencies for you as well, so  you need not worry (check with your bank for any applicable fees).

Enjoy your travels!